# After installing vim-rails plugin I got problems with HAML indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, haml

I've installed vim-rails plugin from Tim Pope. Everything goes well except that I can't run my Rails project into the browser due to a HAML Syntax Error which is is

```
Inconsistent indentation: 6 spaces used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab.
```

Below is a section of my HAML file

```
   .span10
     .span10
       = render 'student_basic_info'
       #actions_bar
         = render 'actions_bar'
     .span10
```

the line "=render 'action_bar'" is where my problem is

In my .vimrc I have "set tabstop=2"

Otherwise, I check the vim-rails/autoload/rails.vim and I see this

```
if ft =~# '^\%(e\=ruby\|yaml|haml|coffee\|css\|s[ac]ss\|lesscss\)\>'
    call self.setvar('&shiftwidth',2)
    call self.setvar('&softtabstop',2)
    call self.setvar('&tabstop',2)
    set noexpandtab
    if exists('+completefunc') && self.getvar('&completefunc') ==# '' 
      call self.setvar('&completefunc','syntaxcomplete#Complete')
    endif
endif
```

That code is setting the tabs for ruby, yaml, haml, coffe, css, sass, scss and lesscss files.

What's going on here? I tried to delete the "set tabstop=2" from my .vimrc but it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may have some tab characters embedded in your file - do a `:retab`, which will convert them to spaces.

I also have `set list listchars=tab:»·` in my .vimrc, which makes tab characters nice and obvious when editing a file. :)

Comment: Awesome! Welcome to the land of the tab-free. :D